# Variable names at the end

Tags: ios, swift

I am going through the new Apple Swift language.

Why should I use variable name at the end ?

```
var largest = 0
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
        }
    }
}
largest
```

Comment: To show the value of it when in a playground? I haven't personally used the language yet, but from the demo that was shown in the keynote that would seem likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking why the last line is `largest`? Paste the code into a playground and you'll see it show the value of largest on the right at that line. It's just so you can see what the value is after the loop.

Comment: does the last line print the value?  Thinking println function is the one to print the values.// I am yet to download Xcode 6. Sorry.

Comment: @Chandu In a normal Xcode project, yes you would use println instead. But in the playground, typing the variable name causes it to be printed.

Comment: If you want to see the value in the console output within playground, then you need to use println(), otherwise as stated, just type the variable name

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the learning book (I see the code sample taken from the iBook) without Xcode; you are missing Xcode's Playground.

Download Xcode 6 Beta, open playground, paste above code, see the magic ;-)

**Playground** is a tool to see what happens in your code as you type.

Also to understand the philosophy behind Xcode Playground take a look at this video:

Bret Victor - Inventing on Principle http://vimeo.com/36579366